How can I determine where deck stairs will land?
I'm in the process of repairing my old deck, and while doing so I want to relocate its stairs. How do I determine how far my last stair should be or where I should build a concrete pad for the last stairs to sit on?
My deck is 97 inches high off the ground straight down. I want the stairs to end somewhere in the general area where the blue lines end.


Note that the reason the stairs bend now is that you need about that many steps and if they don't bend they stick out farther into the yard. You would have to make them much steeper, which in many places violates building codes and can be uncomfortable to navigate (think ship's ladder rather than household staircase). There are some variant designs such as alternate-tread stairs, but those mostly aren't approved by code either since people aren't used to them. Basically, I don't think you have the space to do a straight flight of stairs that your local inspectors will be happy with.

Also, consider that you may need a vertical support in the middle of that straight stair run. i.e. you'll have to sink two new posts to support it, including two new footings.

There are certain standards that stairs should meet for safety. Stairs that aren't what users are accustomed to present a hazard, and those outside common dimensions present challenges for the elderly and the disabled. For those reasons...

Treads should be at least 12" deep. This is easy to achieve with two common 5½" decking boards and a 1" nosing.

Step rise should be between 6½" and 8". Less requires too much stepping, and more can be difficult for some users.


Therefore, the process is a matter of calculating the right number of steps for your total rise (height), after which you can calculate the total run (horizontal length).

Determine the actual total rise. This includes change in grade due to slope. Use a bubble, water, or laser level to take this measurement.

Divide the total rise by 7" (a good step height compromise). Once you have that result, round it up or down to the next whole number, as is your preference. Let's take an example, using your 97" plus say 4" for grade slope:
101 ÷ 7 = 14.4, so we'll round to 14.

Now we'll do the math again, but with the inverse; we'll divide our total rise by the result of the previous step:
101 ÷ 14 = 7.21, which is about 7¼". That's our individual rise (which we'll cut into our stringers*).

Now, take that 14 steps and multiply by tread depth, which we said would be roughly 12". That, of course, is 14'. The nosing of the bottom step will be about 14 feet from the deck rim. Your concrete pad should extend back under the stairs a reasonable distance, like around 8".


Keep in mind that you may lose one tread if you start your steps one rise down instead of at deck level. Take your overall plan into consideration.
Protip for cutting stringers: Once you have all the math done and are marking out the notches with your framing square, remember to slice off the depth of your treads on the bottom end and the depth of your riser at the top end. This leaves you with uniform tread and riser dimensions on the entire set.
I also suggest that you mock up your final dimensions and check that they're suitable for your particular users.
* Note that error in stairs is cumulative. That 0.04" we sort of dismissed when rounding 7.21 to 7¼ adds up to over half an inch in extra height. Combined with any marking error your habits may introduce and you can find yourself with stair treads that slope a bit forward or back. Precision is critical at all stages.

I think I will use the same stairs and move them to the blue line and turn the bend to the left inside of the right. This will require me to set support in the new location. Thank you.

Thanks for the followup, but this doesn't answer the question.
